# Hibernate criterion

Tags: hibernate

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(clazz); 
Criterion rest1= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("A", "X"), 
       Restrictions.in("B", Arrays.asList("X","Y")));
Criterion rest2= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("A", "Y"), 
       Restrictions.eq("B", "Z"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(rest1, rest2));
```

How to create criterion if there are odd number of AND parameters eg. 5?

Comment: If there are 2 paramters with AND it can be done as above but when there are 3 or 5? is there an easy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DetachedCriteria and it will look like:
`Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();`
`disjunction.add(rest1);`
`disjunction.add(rest2);`
`disjunction.add(rest3);`
`...`
`dc.add(disjunction);`

For AND you can use `Conjunction` instead of `Disjunction`.

Comment: Is there any support for HQL regex search?

Answer (score 2):

Just take the result of a previous call to `Restrictions.and()` as one of the parameters to Restrictions.and()

For example:

```
Criterion cr = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("A", "X"), 
       Restrictions.in("B", Arrays.asList("X","Y"))), Restrictions.eq("C", "Z));
```